# Passing multidimensional array to blade using controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to pass multidimensional Array to Blade file using Controller method:

```
        return view('msg.simple', [
            'message' => 'here is my message',
            'links' => [
               [
                    'title' => 'link title 1',
                    'url' => 'www.example.com'
               ],
               [
                    'title' => 'link title 2',
                    'url' => '#2'
               ]
            ]
        ]);
```

view file (blade):

```
@foreach($links as $link)
    <a href="{{$link->url}}">{{$link->title}}</a>
@endforeach
```

but it shows the following error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Possibly related to you passing links in as arrays but trying to access title and url as object properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this :

```
$data = [
            'message' => 'here is my message',
            'links' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'link title 1',
                    'url' => 'www.example.com'
                ],
                [
                    'title' => 'link title 2',
                    'url' => '#2'
                ]
            ]
        ];
        return view('msg.simple',compact('data'));
```

and in view file :

```
        @foreach($data['links'] as $link)
            <a href="{{$link['url']}}">{{$link['title']}}</a>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@foreach($links[0] as $link)
    <a href="{{$link->url}}">{{$link->title}}</a>
@endforeach
```